# How to write an Excel file in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, excel

I just want to write a Excel file in ASP.NET via `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`.

When I run my code in Visual Studio, it works great, but when I publish it to IIS, I get this error and it does not create my Excel file:

> Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space. • To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no longer need. • To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are saving to.

1. I have 30 GB free disk space on my drive
2. Microsoft Office 2016 has been installed on my machine
3. My machine is Windows 10 x64 Pro
4. My path is a folder in IIS on my application root. I tested another path but it doesn't work either
5. I set full access permission for `IIS_IUSRS` on my folder

My c# code:

```
private void CreateExcel(DataSet ds, string excelPath)
{
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        try
        {
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(excelPath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlApp);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch
        {
            obj = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot help with the error, but generally speaking, Excel is [not suited for server-side use](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). That's why more or less pricey commercial solutions like [Aspose](https://products.aspose.com/cells) and [GemBox](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet) exist.

Comment: Do you know a free and popular lib or component to create excel file in ASP.NET?

Comment: KekuSemau listed two; there's also EPPlus. Also some side notes: your try/catch is pointless. All you are doing is rethrowing the exception so there's no need for it. In fact you're destroying the stack trace. If you *must* keep it (for whatever reason) change it to just `throw` instead of `throw ex` this will preserve the stack trace. Second: setting `obj=null` in your `releaseObj` method does **nothing** to the object in the *calling* method. It only sets the *local* variable to `null`. If you want to change it in the calling method, you'd have to pass the parameter with `ref`.

Comment: @motevalizadeh The OpenXML SDK from Microsoft is free, but from all I've read not easy to use unless you make this itself a major project.